# redirect site links form joomla to WordPress

Tags: redirect

I own an old site based on joomla, and I'm planning to build a new site (from the ground up) with WordPress (and Elementor).

What is the best way to redirect the existing site links without losing SEO?
The existing site is based on a subdomain that I want to redirect to the root URL, and other pages that need to be routed manually (individually).

But many pages that I would like to simply be redirected to the home page (or another page) without getting a 404 error.

Comment: unless you plan to have WP itself handle the subdomain I don't think you're helping yourself by limiting research and questions to only WP. Joomla may have a solution for this, and there are plenty of solutions that involve no PHP. Importantly though, you can't ask for a recommendation or a subjective answer, you need a factual answer, and to be able to mark it as not just _a_ answer but _the correct_ answer. Can you edit your question to remove any recommendation aspects and make the question more concrete? Right now it sounds like you need 302 redirects

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate your site from **Joomla to WordPress**, it is essential to ensure that you do not lose the SEO value of your existing site. One of the critical steps in this process is to redirect your old site's URLs to the corresponding pages on your new site.

To redirect your existing site links without losing SEO, **follow these steps:**

1- Create a backup of your Joomla site.

2- Set up your new WordPress site with the Elementor page builder.

3- Install and activate the "Redirection" plugin in WordPress. This plugin will help you manage and create redirects on your site.

4- Set up a 301 permanent redirect for the subdomain of your old site to the root URL of your new site. This redirect will ensure that your users and search engines are directed to your new site's home page. You can set up this redirect using the Redirection plugin by creating a new rule and selecting the "Regex" option. Then, add the following rule:

Source URL: ^subdomain.oldsite.com/(.*)$
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/$1
Match: Regex

For other pages that need to be routed manually, create new redirects using the Redirection plugin. For example, if you had an old page on your Joomla site with the URL "oldsite.com/page1" that you want to redirect to "newsite.com/new-page," create a new rule in the Redirection plugin with the following settings:
Source URL: /page1
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/new-page
Match: URL only

For pages that you want to redirect to the home page or another page without receiving a 404 error, create a new rule in the Redirection plugin with the following settings:
Source URL: /old-page
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/
Match: URL only

By following these steps, you can ensure that your site is fully redirected without losing SEO value. Make sure to test all your redirects before going live to ensure that everything works correctly. **Good luck!**

Comment: Why do I need to backup the old Joomla site? I will be using the same domain, so the only thing that I am changing us the setting in the domain provider – to connect it with the new WordPress server.

Comment: someone knows??